# VBA Function never return to main Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure this out. In my main sub, I call a function. Somehow it ended my run at the end of that function. It displays "Before end" and never displays "I made it out" Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
Sub Main()
      call CopyAndDelete()
      msgbox "I made it out"
End Sub

Function CopyAndDelete()
Dim CopyFromWB As Workbook
Dim CopyToWB As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CopyThisWS As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set CopyToWB = Workbooks("test.xlsm")
CopyToWB.Activate

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "A"
            ws.Delete
        Case "B"
            ws.Delete
        Case "C"
            ws.Delete
        Case "D"
            ws.Delete
    End Select
Next ws

Path = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="choose a file")
FileName = Right(Path, Len(Path) - InStrRev(Path, "\"))
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name = FileName Then
        Workbooks(FileName).Close
    End If
Next wb

Set CopyFromWB = Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set CopyThisWS = CopyFromWB.Worksheets(1)
CopyThisWS.Copy After:=CopyToWB.Worksheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "New A"
CopyFromWB.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Before end"

End Function
```

Comment: It's modal, so it's effectively a break point. So, you have to hit 'OK' on the "Before end" message before "I made it out" gets executed. It should continue running after you clear the first dialog box.

Comment: I actually hit the ok button and that's the end of run. Like I said "I made it out" never display on the screen

Comment: Try making it a `Sub` instead of a `function`

Comment: still doing the same thing

Comment: If you are running it from VBA window, make sure your cursor is inside Main before you hit run. If you are inside CopyAndDelete it will only run that code.

Comment: I did step by step debugging. It started from my main then went into the function. Once I click ok on the "before end" msgbox, the program stops

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Sub Main()
  Call CopyAndDelete
  MsgBox "I made it out"
End Sub

Function CopyAndDelete()
  MsgBox "Before end"
End Function
```

So perhaps you are closing the worksheet you were in when you called the macro?  The Macro should be added to a Module and maybe it needs to be in a Module in the Normal template with the function declared as public:

```
Sub Main()
  Call CopyAndDelete
  MsgBox "I made it out"
End Sub

Public Function CopyAndDelete()
  ... your rest of the code ...
  MsgBox "Before end"
End Function
```

Hth,